# Why Meteor uses it's own Package Manager Atmosphere and not npm?

Tags: meteor, npm

Since Meteor is pure JavaScript, why does it not use CommonJS modules or NPM packages and rather it introduces one of it's own called Atmosphere?

Answer (score 1):

While it is true that meteor *is* pure JavaScript (JS), a ton of that JS is custom-developed to operate in the meteor framework, so it makes sense (to the meteor developer team) to have a website that provides a catalog (and API) for meteor-specific JS libraries.

It's perfectly fine to use `npm` while developing a meteor app, but there is a meteor-specific ecosystem around the JS libraries in atmosphere, that make it easier for developers to find meteor-specific JS libraries.

It is quite common for packaging systems to be created for a specific development environment/purpose not only for technical reasons, but also (and sometimes mostly) for social reasons.

For example, `jar` files are really `tar` files, but having a distinct suffix (and "type") helps the Java apps and developers recognize their own packaging format.  Similarly, Debian `.deb` files are packages specifically for Debian Linux, while Centos/Redhat use RPMs as a packaging format -- even though the contents are effectively identical.

So, Atmosphere is a website for cataloging & delivering meteor-specific JS libraries and apps, for technical reasons as well as a marketing tool to increase awareness of meteor's ecosystem.

Answer (score 1):

There's also a Meteor package, maybe a few others out there too, that allow you to add npm packages to that Meteor package and you're able to make use of it in your Meteor app.

https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm

Also found this on npm. Basically the same thing, it seems:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/meteor-npm